# Loading packages from another directory in Play framework

Tags: java, playframework

By default all my controllers and app files are located in `app` directory. I want to keep my application specific files in `src` directory, and use `app` for framework specific code.

So I have a controller located in `app/controllers/HomeController.java`

```
package controllers;

import chat.model.Message;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class HomeController extends Controller {
    public Result index() {
        Message message = new Message(new String("Hello world!"), new String("John"));
        return ok(index.render(message.message));
    }
}
```

And I have Message class in `src/chat/model/Message.java`

```
package chat.model;

public class Message
{
    public String message;
    public String author;

    public Message(String message, String author) {
        this.message = message;
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Now, I am using activator by Lightbend like Play framework recommends, but I've got error `package chat.model does not exist`. I'am sure it's kind of stupid problem, but I'am struggling with it.

I'am using IntelliJ, and I have `src` marked as sources root, and IntelliJ can see this class(it doesn't shows any error)

Why it don't work?

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you have configured IntelliJ IDEA to recognize the new source directory, but you have not add this new directory to sbt configurations.

How to confirm that? Run the following command inside your application's root directory:

```
sbt "show unmanagedSourceDirectories"
```

The last line will be something like:

```
[info] List(/your/app/directory/app-2.11, /your/app/directory/app, /your/app/directory/app)
```

That is the list of source directories recognized by sbt. To add another directory (`src`), just [follow the docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Add+an+additional+source+directory) and add the line below to your `build.sbt` file:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "src"
```

After that, reimport the project to IntelliJ - if you are not using the auto-import feature - and it will automatically recognize the src directory. Finally, you can also use the [default sbt layout](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy#Default-SBT-layout) for your Play application.